# iOS CSS shading issue

Tags: css, ipad, ios

How do I remove the shading on a button on iPad. The standard submit button when colored and with rounded corners has a gradient that is automatically applied. I've searched all over, but can't seem to get rid of it! :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Of course, you will need to add your own css styles to make it look like a button.